Duplicate Profile Entry When Order trying to save shipment
I have upgraded drupal from 9.5 to 10.2.5 and upgraded commerce_shipping to version 2.2.2. Then I am getting an error when I try to checkout:
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint 
violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '13109' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO "profile" 
("profile_id", "revision_id", "type", "uuid", "status", "uid", "is_default", "data", 
"created", "changed") VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, 
:db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, 
:db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, 
:db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array ( 
[:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 13109 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 13109   
[:db_insert_placeholder_2] => customer [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => cf849757-d6f0- 
467a-aa41-dfc4b4489ec7 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 
135275 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => a:1: 
{s:23:"address_book_profile_id";s:5:"13109";} [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 
1710227063 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 1710227063 ) in 
Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 817 of 
core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
Drupal\Core\Database\StatementWrapperIterator->execute() (Line: 44)
Drupal\mysql\Driver\Database\mysql\Insert->execute() (Line: 948)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->doSaveFieldItems() (Line: 718)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doSave() (Line: 486)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save() (Line: 806)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (Line: 354)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase->save() (Line: 319)
Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem->preSave() (Line: 263)
    Drupal\entity_reference_revisions\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceRevisionsItem->preSave() (Line: 233)
Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList->delegateMethod() (Line: 191)
Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList->preSave() (Line: 938)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->invokeFieldMethod() (Line: 888)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->invokeHook() (Line: 56)
Drupal\commerce\CommerceContentEntityStorage->invokeHook() (Line: 529)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->doPreSave() (Line: 753)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doPreSave() (Line: 483)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save() (Line: 806)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (Line: 354)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase->save() (Line: 55)
Drupal\commerce_shipping\LateOrderProcessor->process() (Line: 196)
Drupal\commerce_order\OrderRefresh->refresh() (Line: 123)
Drupal\commerce_order\OrderStorage->doOrderPreSave() (Line: 86)
Drupal\commerce_order\OrderStorage->invokeHook() (Line: 529)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->doPreSave() (Line: 753)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doPreSave() (Line: 483)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save() (Line: 806)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (Line: 169)
Drupal\commerce_order\OrderStorage->save() (Line: 354)
 Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase->save() (Line: 358)
Drupal\commerce_shipping\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\ShippingInformation->buildPaneForm() (Line: 546)
Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutFlow\CheckoutFlowWithPanesBase->buildForm()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 536)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->retrieveForm() (Line: 283)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm() (Line: 224)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->getForm() (Line: 143)
Drupal\commerce_checkout\Controller\CheckoutController->formPage()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 627)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext() (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 181)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 76)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\redirect_after_login\RedirectMiddleware->handle() (Line: 54)
Drupal\simple_oauth\HttpMiddleware\BasicAuthSwap->handle() (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 28)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle() (Line: 32)
Drupal\big_pipe\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle() (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass() (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 43)
Drupal\webform_product\RedirectMiddleware->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line: 36)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\AjaxPageState->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 704)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)

I found out its happening when order is trying to save shipments in file commerce_shipping/src/Plugin/Commerce/CheckoutPane/ShippingInformation.php --> buildPaneForm line number349
// Update the shipments and save the order if no rate was explicitly

// selected, that usually occurs when changing addresses, this will ensure

// the default rate is selected/applied.

if (!$this->hasRateSelected($pane_form, $form_state) && ($recalculate_shipping || $force_packing)) {

  array_map(function (ShipmentInterface $shipment) {

    if (!$shipment->isNew()) {

      $shipment->save();

    }

  }, $shipments);

  $this->order->set('shipments', $shipments); // this one is causing error.

  $this->order->save();

Please help me guys, how I can resolve this issue.
